# Close .Auth/login/done after MSAL login successful in Xamarin application

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-msal

I have been setting up AD(MSAL) Authentication using azure with my application but am having an issue closing the window that appears after successful sign in. The page that appears within the embedded browser with the link returning to my API homepage simply states "You have successfully signed in" with a link below to return to previous page with goes to my API home page.

The below is my code in my App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static IPublicClientApplication PCA = null;

    public static string ClientID = "********-****-****-****-**********";

    public static string[] Scopes = { "User.Read" };
    public static string Username = string.Empty;

    public static object ParentWindow { get; set; }

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnStart()
    {
        PCA = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientID)
            //.WithRedirectUri($"msal{ClientID}://auth")
            .WithRedirectUri("https://kpiapp-api-dev.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback")
            .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup("com.microsoft.adalcache")
            .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "********-****-****-****-**********") //TenantID
            .Build();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());

    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
```

And my Loginpage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async void OnSignIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
        IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await App.PCA.GetAccountsAsync();

        var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;
        bool connectionFound = false;

        if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
        {
            connectionFound = true;
        }

        string APIData = "";

        if(connectionFound == true)
        {

            try
            {
                if (SignInButton.Text == "Sign in")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        IAccount firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
                        authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenSilent(App.Scopes, firstAccount)
                                                .ExecuteAsync();

                    }
                    catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(App.Scopes)
                                                        .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.ParentWindow)
                                                        .ExecuteAsync();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex2)
                        {
                            await DisplayAlert("Acquire token interactive failed. See exception message for details: ", ex2.Message, "Dismiss");
                        }
                    }

                    if (authResult != null)
                    {
                        var content = await GetHttpContentWithTokenAsync(authResult.AccessToken);

                        SignInButton.Text = "Sign out";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    while (accounts.Any())
                    {
                        await App.PCA.RemoveAsync(accounts.FirstOrDefault());
                        accounts = await App.PCA.GetAccountsAsync();
                    }
});
                    SignInButton.Text = "Sign in";

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Authentication failed. See exception message for details: ", ex.Message, "Dismiss");
            }

            await Task.Yield();

            APIData = getAPIData();

        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Connection Error", "Check your internet connection and try again", "Try again");
        }

        if (APIData != "ConnectionError")
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage(APIData));
        }
        else
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            await DisplayAlert("API Download error", "Error connecting to API", "Try again");
        }
    //MainPage = new MainPage(APIData);
}

    public async Task<string> GetHttpContentWithTokenAsync(string token)
    {
        try
        {
            //get data from API
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me");
            message.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);
            string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("API call to graph failed: ", ex.Message, "Dismiss");
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }

    private string getAPIData()
    {
        string APIData = "";

        try
        {
            APIData = new WebClient().DownloadString("****/api/data");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            APIData = "ConnectionError";
        }

        return APIData;
    }
}
```

I'm aware this is doing nothing with that sign in and won't access the api data at the moment. I'm really just looking to get the authentication window closed and then work from there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue, by adding .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true) to the second call of authResult so it appears like this:

```
catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
{
    try
    {
         authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(App.Scopes)
                                      .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.ParentWindow)
                                      .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                                      .ExecuteAsync();
     }
     catch (Exception ex2)
     {
         await DisplayAlert("Acquire token interactive failed. See exception message for details: ", ex2.Message, "Dismiss");
     }
}
```